# how to convert a nested dictionary to a list, combine it with existing list and display results

Tags: python, list, dictionary

#nested dictionary

```
card_values = {
"normal": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 
"suited": {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10, "A":11}
}
```

#code I wrote to try and iterate over the values

```
all_cards = []
for i in card_values:
    for j in card_values[i]:
        if j == "J" or j == "Q" or j == "K":
            all_cards.append(10)
        elif j =="A":
            all_cards.append(11)
        else:
            all_cards.append(j)
print(all_cards)
```

without doing this, can we call the value corresponding to the key inside the nested dictionary in a for loop?

#output needed

```
all_cards = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make a set to get the unique values and then sort it.

```
card_values = {
    "normal": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "suited": {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10, "A":11}
}

all_cards = sorted(
    set(card_values["normal"])
    | set(card_values["suited"].values())
)

print(all_cards)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet:

```
values = list(set(card_values["normal"] + list(card_values["suited"].values())))
```

this returns :

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]
```

what each part of the code is doing:
We are first getting `[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` from the `"normal"` key in `card_values`. Then we are getting only the values from the `"suited"` key in `card_values` and then converting them to a list which leaves `[10, 10, 10, 11]`. We then combine these two lists and use `set()` to remove duplicates.

Comment: what if there is another dictionary inside the nested one?
`
card_values = {
    "normal": [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
    "suited": {"J":10, "Q":10, "K":10, "A":11, "Q": {"a": 13}}
}
all_cards = sorted(
    set(card_values["normal"])
    | set(card_values["suited"].values())
    | set(card_values["suited"]["Q"].value()))   #how do I change this so it works

print(all_cards)
`